# Can I use toggle bolts to install faux wood beams to the drywall in the ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, safety, bolts

Unfortunately the ceiling ceiling joists run in the wrong direction.
I was wondering if I can use toggle bolts to support ~50 pounds of faux wood beams on ceiling dry wall.

It would be about 4 toggle bolts across a 16.5 ft ceiling holding up ~50 pounds of weight.

Comment: Maybe on a vertical wall where the load is perpendicular to the bolt.  But 50 pounds pulling straight down?  You'll need a dusk mask and a good vacuum cleaner!  That being said, you can always test it on some scrap drywall.  Remember though, the drywall itself may come loose.

Comment: You may still get them to stay up, depending on how wide they are, and it will take a lot of work. So how wide are they?  Another question, if you line them up under joists, why would not that work? Go every other joist, or every third to mimic the spacing you need.

Comment: what's above the ceiling joists?

Answer (score 4):

Is there an attic above that leaves the joists accessible? Add 2x6 blocking between the joists to get the support you need. Toenail the blocking to the joists on both sides of the blocking. Then you can fasten the faux beam to the blocking rather than the drywall.

Comment: I think this is good advice adding a few blocks would be much better and safer all the way around +

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend it. That much weight, even with double the toggles holding will still be an issue in my opinion. Starting with the fasteners that hold the drywall. They are meant to only hold the drywall. Drywall barely stays flat on a ceiling with 24" framing centers. !6' centers is better, but still, I do not want to imagine what would go on with 50 lbs of downward force applied to it 24/7/128.... Why 128?, because I don't think it will last 365

Comment: I agree , over time the Sheetrock will probably sag , blocking isn’t probably the safest bet.

Comment: There was no mention of blocking, but if it could be added, thats why I asked in the comment above "how wide is the beam". It is possible to add blocking above the ceiling and use the beam to cover the access holes

Comment: Represton’s answer covered blocking but yours on sag is also good+

Comment: @EdBeal, yes I missed that, I answered as if there is a living space above. I did not consider an attic space....

Answer (score 0):

50 pounds weight will likely pull the drywall down on top of you.

If you can run the beams all the way to the walls and support their weight on the wall instead of the ceiling that would work much better.

Another option  would be to put expanding braces like used to hang ceiling fans inside the ceiling and use the beams to cover the holes

yet another it to cut a 2" hole and using a drill extension to drove a self drilling screw screw attach a wire to the joists either side of the hole.

[image]

The attachment of the wire to the joist could be by a two-hole angle bracket with one hole for the screw and the wire hooked through the other hole and twisted.  you're going to want to use hex or square drive screws here because you're driving them one-handed.

the wire carries a [coupling nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_nut) that has been drilled through for the wire, screw some all thread in there to provide a hanger point and to fix the nut in position on the wire.
[image]